# What to do with troll answers?

Tags: discussion

So, as you may have noticed, there have been a number of answers that are obvious troll answers, as while they might possibly work, they are either highly inconvenient or provided simply for humor value. The main place I have seen these is on questions that make it to HNQ and generate a lot of views. Examples of this where jumping on your bagel, or putting it in a bag and sitting on it. [This](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/10971/11641) answer also seems to be in the same category. The two answers on the bagel question were deleted, so to me it seems like they should be flagged as VLQ and deleted, so I ask you, what should we do with these answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any post you feel is not *sincerely* trying to ask or answer a question, 'flag' it for moderator attention; it should be **removed**. That includes anything being posted in bad faith or just to be funny.

The problem with a *post-just-for-the-laughs* is they're just pandering to the crowd and tend to draw a lot of undue attention, and soon folks are joining in kind just to one-up the next guy. It's a tough thing to reel back in once it gets started, so **we just don't do it at all.**

(and honestly, most people are just *not* that funny :P)